# Changing the names of radio buttons but they don't change when I run the code

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```js
<input class="star star-5" value="5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" />
<label class="star star-5" value="5" for="star-5"></label readonly=" readonly">
<input class="star star-4" value="4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" />
<label class="star star-4" value="4" for="star-4"></label readonly=" readonly">
<input class="star star-3" value="3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" />
<label class="star star-3" value="3" for="star-3"></label readonly=" readonly">
<input class="star star-2" value="2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" />
<label class="star star-2" value="2" for="star-2"></label readonly=" readonly">
<input class="star star-1" value="1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" />
<label class="star star-1" value="1" for="star-1"></label readonly=" readonly">
</div>`);

//output+= '<input type="checkbox" value='+dataList+' name="box2">'  + '   ' + dataList+'   '+'<br><br>';
output1+=  '<input class="star star-1" value="1" id="star-1" type="radio" name= "star"'+numberOfSubquestion+'/>';
numberOfSubquestion++;
output2+=  '<input class="star star-2" value="2" id="star-2" type="radio" name= "star"'+numberOfSubquestion+'/>';
numberOfSubquestion++;
output3+=  '<input class="star star-3" value="3" id="star-3" type="radio" name= "star"'+numberOfSubquestion+'/>';
numberOfSubquestion++;
output4+=  '<input class="star star-4" value="4" id="star-4" type="radio" name= "star"'+numberOfSubquestion+'/>';
numberOfSubquestion++;
output5+=  '<input class="star star-5" value="5" id="star-5" type="radio" name= "star"'+numberOfSubquestion+'/>';
numberOfSubquestion++;

document.getElementById("star-1").innerHTML=output1;
document.getElementById("star-2").innerHTML=output2;
document.getElementById("star-3").innerHTML=output3;
document.getElementById("star-4").innerHTML=output4;
document.getElementById("star-5").innerHTML=output5;
```

I wonder if I somehow can change the names before they run. Even though I change the names after when I run the code the names are the old ones. Because when I rerun the function the radio buttons act as they are one unit.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the code a [mre]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar).

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect here: `"star"'+numberOfSubquestion+'` If you want the element to have the number inside the name. This will result in `<input ... name="star"1 />`

Comment: Inputs have no innerHTML property

Comment: Radios do not have inner HTML, use the labels if you must but I suggest you generate the whole thing from an array

Comment: How can I generate it from an array?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid and input fields do not have innerHTML

Here is one way of creating what you want

```js
const numberOfSubquestion = 1
document.getElementById("ratingDiv").innerHTML = Array.from({length:5})
 .map((_,i) => `<input class="star star-${5-i}" value="${5-i}" id="star-${5-i}" type="radio" name="star${numberOfSubquestion}" />
 <label class="star star-${5-i}" for="star-${5-i}"></label>`).join("")
```

```html
<div id="ratingDiv"></div>
```